# Combining two functions to hide element

Tags: jquery

I have the following three functions:

```
$(".redDiv").hover(function() {
   $(".blueDiv").show();
}, function() {
    $(".blueDiv").hide();
});
$(".blueDiv").hover(function() {
    $(this).show();
}, function() {
    $(this).hide();
});

$(document).click(function(e) {
    if (!$(".ignoreClick").is(e.target)) {
        $("div").hide();
    }
});
```

Quite simple, when a mouse hovers over `.redDiv` or `.blueDiv` it is shown. Also if a user clicks anywhere in the document -- all divs suppose to be hidden. the only exception for this click if a clicked element has an `.ignoreClick` class in it.

I need it to hide `blueDiv` on click even if the mouse is over it.  For some reason that does not work. What am I missing?

Comment: _What am I missing?_  a jsfiddle.net test case?

Comment: I personally like jsfiddle and always +1 those using it, but I also saw some complaints about placing code outside StackOverflow...

Comment: sure, they need to have _some_ code here, but often a complete test case is too long to include in its entirety.

Comment: Perhaps SO needs to buy jsfiddle? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `event.stopPropagation` in an event handler for the `.ignoreClick` elements to stop hiding all the divs on document click (the event will not bubble up to the `document` element).

Also if you fade-out-in the div elements rather than `show`/`hide`ing them they will still occupy their spot on the document. If you use `show`/`hide` then the element will no longer be in the flow of the page and you won't be able to mouse-over any hidden elements to make them show again. If you change the `opacity` of the divs instead then you can mouse-over a hidden div and it will show up:

```
var $redDivs  = $('.redDiv'),
    $blueDivs = $('.blueDiv'),
    $ignore   = $('.ignoreClick');
$redDivs.hover(
      function () {         
        $blueDivs.stop().fadeTo(100, 1);
    },
      function () {
        $blueDivs.stop().fadeTo(100, 0);
      }                     
);    
$blueDivs.hover(
      function () {
        $(this).stop().fadeTo(100, 1);
      },
      function () {
        $(this).stop().fadeTo(100, 0);
      }                     
);

$ignore.bind('click', function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).click(function(e) {
    $redDivs.add($blueDivs).add($ignore).stop().fadeTo(100, 0);
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/E5f6N/2/

Notice I cached all the selectors, this will help the code run more efficiently.

Docs for `.fadeTo()`: http://api.jquery.com/fadeto

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
$(document).click(function(e) {

    $('body').addClass('allHidden');

    if (!$(".ignoreClick").is(e.target)) {
        $("div").hide();
    }
});
$(".blueDiv").hover(function() {

    if(!$('body').hasClass('allHidden')){
        $(this).show();
    });

}, function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
```